# Intellij IDEA Docker view does not show logs

Tags: docker, intellij-idea

I set my docker config under Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Docker
with TCP address https://192.168.99.100:2376, as stated under official JetBrains tutorial with the certificates path pointing to that of the default virtual machine. The connection is also succesfully established and under docker view I can see the container running with volume/port bindings, properties etc. recognized properly. The one thing that I miss are the logs. This tab is empty though the server.log file on the vm is being filled when I execute commands. Why are the logs not being displayed in the docker view of my Intellij IDEA ultimate 2018.3?

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I will but first of all I'd really understand this unexpected behavior when I see my colleague's PC with the same version of IDEA (I got the installer from him) showing the logs properly.